# Java regexp - get parts of string

Tags: java, regex

I've a string contains `"unlimited symbols count... [ioiwego|gerqge]"` (without brackets). I need get characters from `[` to `]` split it on `|` if the string contains it. Finally I need get from `[ergerg|gererh] smth like this ergerg (gererh)`. first string in `[|]` (before `|`) may contain only numbers, letters, dots `(.)` and underscore `(_)`. How I can do it?

Comment: By testing a pattern and printing out the output `String[]` until satisfied with the result.

Comment: By writing code. Have you tried it? How did it go?

Comment: Then [edit] your question, post your code, and describe problem you are having with it. Stack Overflow is not code-writing service, and this question is pure code-writing-request. Also tone down a bit. My comment was sarcastic, but its purpose was to make you realise that your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 0):

For the first pattern:

```
"unlimited symbols count... [ioiwego|gerqge]".replaceAll("([^[]*\[)|(\][^\]]*)","").split("|")
```

For the second pattern

```
"[ergerg|gererh] smth like this ergerg (gererh)".matches("[^[]*\[[\._a-zA-Z-0-9]*\|[^\]]*\][^\]]*")
```